# add icloud destination to path in terminal

Tags: macos, path, bash, icloud-drive

I want to add destination of iCloud drive folder to PATH in terminal.
I tried to add this line to .bash_profile (that path works with cd command)

```
export PATH="~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Scripts:$PATH"
```

and nothing happened. Even `...com\~apple\~CloudDocs...` doesn't work.
After calling `echo $PATH`, there was added entire path to iCloud drive exactly how I wanted. But when I call any of scripts located in that path `No such file or directory` error occurs.
When I rewrite .bash_profile file to export `export PATH="~/.Scripts:$PATH"` and relocate scripts there, everything works.

Comment: It may be best to create a symlink to that folder and add that to your PATH. Thus avoiding any tilde issues.

Comment: Simple solution. thanks. Works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a little bash code analysis, it looks like if your path beings with `~`, then any subsequent `~` in the path is affected.

From tilde.c

```
/* Scan through STRING expanding tildes as we come to them. */
while (1)
```

Instead of using `~/Library/...`,

try `/Users/[user]/Library/...`